# Sent SMTP email using my own server failed

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I have set up `Mail Server` using `MailEnable` and configured my domain as my DNS name (i am using dlinkddns account) with `Outlook` and my account works fine when received emails but emails that sent  - i cannot see in the other mailbox (i try Gmail)

Now all i want to do is send email using `.Net` and this is what i have try:

```
private string from = MyUser@MyDomain;

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.Subject = "My subject";
mail.Body = "My body";
mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(MyDomain);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, myPassword);

try
{
    client.Send(mail);  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
}
```

And this is the error that received:

```
Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.
```

Answer (score 0):

`client.UseDefaultCredentials` should be set to `false` if you're supplying credentials;

Comment: After changed it to false it still failed with same error

Comment: The error indicates that you're not even trying to authenticate, and you're still getting the exact same thing after setting UseDefaultCredentials to false?

Comment: According to a quick Google search... change the authentication type from "MailEnable integrated authentication" to "Authenticate against the following username/password.", then enter the username and password.

Comment: What do you mean change "MailEnable integrated authentication" to "Authenticate against the following username/password." ? i cannot find it in my code

Comment: I'm suggesting that the problem is not in your code, but rather in your MailEnable configuration.